# Access elements values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

How do I retrieve element's `clientWidth` and `scrollWidth`? using `getCssValue` doesn't work

```
$('.grid-header-col .title').getCssValue('scrollWidth')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`getAttribute()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute) instead:

```
element(by.css('.grid-header-col .title')).getAttribute('scrollWidth');
```

Answer (score 0):

Both scrollWidth and clientWidth are properties of DOM element. So you need to get the dom element first by attaching [0] after a jquery object and then retreive the properties.

```
$('.grid-header-col .title')[0].scrollWidth
$('.grid-header-col .title')[0].clientWidth
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bruceyang/qa80t37g/)